# TextField return nil if never reselected

Tags: swift, realm, segment

In my EditVC, I performed segue from selected CellForRow At indexPath to editVC.

In Edit VC. I want to expect results of data return as it is IF there is no modification. However, issue is if I did not rechoose/reselect the row at pickerView again, it will auto return nil.

I want to have results of if User did not modify the data/specific data only, other data will remain the same.

This is the results of print statement.

**// This results is perform correctly for what I want IF I RESELECT THE PICKERVIEW IN TEXTFIELD BUT WILL AMEND MY CATEGORY DATABASE AS WELL.**

currentTransaction.categoryID : Optional(9)

selectedCategory.categoryID : 9

currentTransaction.categoryTypeID : Optional(1)

selectedCategory.categoryTypeID : 1

currentTransaction.categorytype.name = Optional("EXPENSE 9")

selectedCategory.name = EXPENSE 9

**// If I never reselect the pickerview in textfield**

currentTransaction.categoryID : Optional(0) **/* Suppose to be 9 */**

selectedCategory.categoryID : 0 **/* Suppose to be 9 */**

currentTransaction.categoryTypeID : Optional(0) **/* Suppose to be 1 */**

selectedCategory.categoryTypeID : 0 **/* Suppose to be 1 */**

currentTransaction.categoryType.name = Optional("") **/* Suppose to be EXPENSE 9 */**

selectedCategory.name = **/* Suppose to be EXPENSE 9 */**

```
class EditTransactionTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var selectedTransaction : Transaction? //selectedTransaction From TransactionVC's CellForRow

    var categories : Results<Category>!
    var currentCategories : Results<Category>!
    var selectedCategory = Category()


    @IBOutlet weak var amountTF: UITextField!

    //PickerView for keyboard
    lazy var pickerView : UIPickerView = UIPickerView()
    //Segment Control
    @IBOutlet weak var categorySCoutlet: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryTF: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        amountTF.text = selectedTransaction?.amount
        categoryTF.text = selectedTransaction?.categoryType?.name
        categorySCoutlet.selectedSegmentIndex = selectedTransaction?.categoryType?.categoryTypeID as! Int



        loadData()
        setupPicker()
    }


    @IBAction func categoryTypeSC(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        guard let type = CategoryType(id: sender.selectedSegmentIndex) else {
            fatalError("error")
        }
        currentCategories = categories.filter("categoryTypeID == %@", type.rawValue)
        categoryTF.text = currentCategories.first?.name
        pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
//        pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)

    }


    //MARK:- Edit Transaction Btn

    @IBAction func editTransactionButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let currentTransaction = selectedTransaction {
            try! realm.write {
                currentTransaction.amount = amountTF.text!


                //Success modification if got RESELECT row of category BUT will return "" if never reselect and cause categories list become chosen categoryID, name , and type
                currentTransaction.categoryType?.categoryID = selectedCategory.categoryID
                currentTransaction.categoryType?.categoryTypeID = selectedCategory.categoryTypeID
                currentTransaction.categoryType!.name = selectedCategory.name



                print("currenttransaction.categoryID : \(currentTransaction.categoryType?.categoryID)")
                print("selectedCategory.categoryID : \(selectedCategory.categoryID)")

                print("currenttransaction.categoryTypeID : \(currentTransaction.categoryType?.categoryTypeID)")
                print("selectedCategory.categoryTypeID : \(selectedCategory.categoryTypeID)")

                print("currenttranasction.categorytype.name = \(currentTransaction.categoryType?.name)")
                print("selectedcategory.name = \(selectedCategory.name)")

            }

        }



        DataManager.shared.transVC.tableView.reloadData()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }




    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        if touches.first?.view == view {
            categoryTF.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    // MARK: - Data Manipulation
    func loadData() {
        categories = realm.objects(Category.self)
    }
}

//MARK:- UIPICKERVIEW DELEGATE

extension EditTransactionTableViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return currentCategories.count
    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return currentCategories[row].name
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        categoryTF.text = currentCategories[row].name
        selectedCategory = currentCategories[row]

    }

    //MARK:- Picker Helper
    func setupPicker() {
//        currentCategories = categories.filter("categoryTypeID == %@", CategoryType.income.rawValue)
        currentCategories = categories.filter("categoryTypeID == %@", selectedTransaction?.categoryType?.categoryTypeID)

        categoryTF.inputView = pickerView

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self

        categorySCoutlet.setTitle("Income", forSegmentAt: 0)
        categorySCoutlet.setTitle("Expense", forSegmentAt: 1)
        categorySCoutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(categoryTypeSC(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    }
}
```

Comment: What your seeing is correct for the presented code. selectedCategory is only populated when you select the row in the pickerView. See in this function `func pickerView:didSelectRow` you have this line of code `selectedCategory = currentCategories[row]`? That's the only place `selectedCategory` is populated so otherwise it will only contain it's default values `var selectedCategory = Category()`

Comment: In what way I should counter this problem? Mind giving me a guide? This is my first app development and first time performing this kind of issue.

Comment: It's not really a problem as that's how you've coded it. If nothing is selected in the pickerView then nothing will be returned. In other words, if the user took no action then there's nothing to change, right? So if the user took no action in the pickerView, you don't need to write/update any data in Realm e.g. if it returns nil that means the user made no changes so don't attempt to write any data.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. I had solve it using if statement by your sense.